# sipp generate random string in scenario

Tags: sip

I have created a program that uses sipp for sip trafic generation. would like to generate a random numver for the destination randomly and at run time without injecting from external csv. Currently I am doing the same for the originator using the [service] command. Is there another command I can use from comman line? Can I generate a random number from inside the scenario?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to make SIPp directly generate a random number. But if you have access to common Unix utilities, you can provide it via the command line.

But I am not sure what you want to do.

If you want to perform *one* call, you can provide the random destination in the command line thanks to `set` command line parameter.

Example:

```
mydest=`n=8; rand -M $((10**${n})) | awk "{ printf(\"%0${n}u\", \\$1) }"`
sipp ... -set service_route mydest $mydest
```

(replace n=8 by the number of digits you want. If you don't want a fixed number of digits, just remove the awk part)

Then you declare your variable at the beginning of your SIPp script:

```
<Global variables="mydest" />
<Reference variables="mydest" />
```

Afterwards you can place it in SIP messages by using `[$mydest]`.

But if you want to perform lots of calls from the same SIPp launch, you can generate on the fly a CSV file with random numbers.

Example:

```
n=8; echo "RANDOM" > zrandom; rand -e -N 1000000 -d "\n" -M $((10**${n})) | awk "{ printf(\"%0${n}u\n\", \$1) }" >> zrandom
sipp ... -inf zrandom
```

(same remark: replace n=8 by the number of digits you want. If you don't want a fixed number of digits, just remove the awk part)